# Angular : relative navigation from an Observable subscription

Tags: angular

I need help about a specific case in my Angular app.
I would like to perform a relative navigation after a REST call is done.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private myservice: MyService) { }

myAction() {
    this.myservice.performCall().subscribe(
        value => {
           console.log('Redirection needed'); // is called
           this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});  // Doesn't do anything
        }
    );
}
```

The log is well done, but I stay on the same component. If I change it into an absolute navigation, it's working as expected.

But I really need the relative one because my component can be reached from multiple urls.
Is it possible ? How ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with `this.activatedRoute`? What is this variable?

Comment: It's the ActivatedRoute injected in the constructor of my component.
If I use this navigation line into a method trigger on a button click, it's working. It looks like be linked to the subscription .

I edited my message to add the constructor.

Comment: Maybe try this `this.router.navigate(['.'], { relativeTo: this. this.activatedRoute.parent });`

Comment: Yes, it's working now. by user the ```.parent```.
Thank you very much. You save my day :)

Comment: please mark the answer to make this question useful for other people ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change navigation to

```js
this.router.navigate(['.'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent });
```